Hydraulic eng. problem
I need to solve this problem for a university course and I’m not sure how to. I’d really appreciate any help. The question is translated to English so I hope it still makes sense. I have a drawing to visualise it, but I’m not sure if I can post pictures here?
Thanks for help!
A rectangular irrigation channel with a base width of 5 m is made of concrete (with wooden formwork). The longitudinal drop of the channel is 1 ‰. There is an obstacle with a height of 20 cm in the channel.a) Calculate the water height at the obstacle (tip: calculate the flow first) b) Calculate the energy heights at the various points.
c) Draw the different water heights and energy levels in the drawing.

use the button that looks like mountains and sun to add picture

You will need to attempt a solution before we'll help with homework problems.

hint: calculate the flow first.
